# How to place div right after input box?

Tags: css

How do I get the '.domain.com' right after the 'subdomain' input box ?

```
<div style="display:block; ">
<input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;">
<div style="float: right;">.domain.com</div>
</div>
```

​
http://jsfiddle.net/Tmusf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;float: left;">
<div style="float: left;">.domain.com</div>
```

example http://jsfiddle.net/Tmusf/1/

Comment: -1 There isn't any need to use float: left; to both the elements

Comment: And those who have upvoted to this answer would you please tell me why this is useful. Here, the float property is not necessary at all because input is an inline element

Comment: @Dipaks hey man both will work fine.. But this is simple and basic usage of css ...

Comment: It's not! It's wrong use of CSS... please explain why float is necessary here?

Answer (score 1):

now used to this

```
    <div style="display:block; ">
<input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;vertical-align:top;">
<div style="vertical-align:top; display:inline-block;">.domain.com</div>
</div>
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/NqJ4mAwm

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS to `<div style="display: inline">.domain.com</div>`

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Tmusf/2/

```
<div style="display:block; ">
  <input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;">
  <div style="display: inline">.domain.com</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use some `inline element` like `span` instead of `div` and you don't have to style it

```
<div style="display:block; ">
      <input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;">
      <span>.domain.com</span>
    </div>
```

Or you can directly add `.domain.com` text without any container

```
<div style="display:block; ">
          <input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;">
          .domain.com
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display: block;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;" />.domain.com
    </div>
```

As Dipaks code, Above is the easiest and simplest solution for your problem. If you want to give some styles, give it in a  tag.

Example:

```
<div style="display: block;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="subdomain" style="width: 245px;" /><span         style="color:Blue;">.domain.com</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is an best answer for you

```
<div class="field">
     <input type="text" value="" class="field_site" id="site_address" name="site_address">
     <span class="text_inner">.example.com</span> 
      </div>

      <style>
       .field {
        border: 1px solid #C7C7C7;
        height: 30px;
        width: 300px;
    }
    .field_site {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        border: medium none;
        height: 30px;
        width: 200px;
    }
    .text_inner {
        color: #999999;
    }
      </style>
```